# Copying a variable in python

Tags: python, numpy, copy

This question has been discussed many times but I am still very confused about it. 
The following code snippet illustrates the problem:

```
a = np.arange(10)
m = a
m[0] = 1000
m
Out[106]: array([1000,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    
9])
a
Out[107]: array([1000,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9])
```

Now let's do

```
a = np.arange(10)
m = a
m = m + 1000
m
Out[102]: array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109])
a
Out[103]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I'd like to fully understand the reason why the variable a is not modified when computing m = m + 1000. I don't understand the logic here....

Comment: I guess you meant `array([1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009])`, right?

Comment: `m = a` does not create a new array; `m + 1000` does. Be sure you have read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: The *object* referred to by `a` is not modified because that object is not mutates by the assignment statement `m = ...` nor by the addition operation.

Answer (score 6):

You found the difference between `a = a + b` and `a += b`.  The first creates a *new* value (`a + b`) and assigns it to the variable left of the `=` (`a`).  The second *changes* the value left of the `+=` (the array which is held by `a` and `m`) and all variables which hold this value (`a` and `m`) reflect the change.

If you try it with `+=` instead, both `a` and `m` are changed as they both hold the same value:

```
a = np.arange(10)
m = a
m += 1000
a
```

This shows:

```
array([1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009])
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that there is no guarantee that `+=` will modify an object in-place

Comment: Alfe, this is very useful. But now consider: a = 1    then m = a  then m+=1. In this case m will be incremented, not a. Why?

Comment: Because in this case the value is not a reference to an object.  A mere `int` is just a primitive value (you cannot change a `5` to be a `6`), and a variable holding such a primitive will be given another primitive value in case of a `+=` being applied to it.  The `+=` will change a value if that value is *mutable* (like a `list` or `dict` or `np.array`), it will fail with an error if the value is *immutable* (like a `tuple`), or it will replace the value if it is a primitive (like an `int`, `float` or `str`).